# Django with postgresql deployment on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I’ve been trying to deploy a django application with postgresql db on aws elastic beanstalk and i ran into many issues that i surfed and solved. Now the application uploads fine however the environment is still not green and I constantly am receiving 502 bad gateway nginx. I’ve checked nginx logs which say 111 connection refused etc. I’ve tried changed the port to 8001 from 8000 but didn’t work out. Somebody please guide me on how to deploy my application successfully.

Comment: What errors do you get exactly? Have you inspected EB log files?

Comment: @Marcin Thank you for asking! The cfn-init.log says that the build is complete. The eb-engine.log says that the instance deployment completed successfully. Where as, the nginx/error.log says:  *9100 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
 172.31.15.199, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "54.186.126.153"

Comment: @AzherAleem did you ever get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the common errors logfiles. Try checking them out

```
--- Common Dbug Errors ---
    $ eb logs
    --Files (after eb ssh):
    $ eb ssh
    1.sudo nano /var/log/cfn-init.log
    2.sudo nano /var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log (see command output and error from config)
```

And are you using AWS RDS to for PostgreSQL?
Here is a detailed explanation and some common error fixes discuss in this [blog](https://miraiblogs.com/deploy-django-awseb/)